# Connection to a user from RunSQL Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a user manually through the interface of SQLDeveloper and granted the user the "connect" role, but when i try to connect to that user from RunSQL it says : ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
knowing that i am carefully typing both the username and the password.
What could be going wrong please?

For comparaison when i created a connection to my database from SQLDevelper i found a user that was created from the RunSQL and was similar to the user i just created (from SQLDeveloper), that user connects normally but the user newly created does not.